# SAP HANA getting CSV data size

Tags: csv, memory, hana

I am working with SAP HANA I would like to know if it is possible to get disk size of CSV data with SQL.

The CSV data that I mean is the file `\index\SCHEMA NAME\CL\TABLE_NAME\data.csv` after export.

Best Regards
Houssem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is no way to generate this directly.\

You could, however, do some rough estimation, by looking at M_CS_COLUMNS to see the estimated uncompressed size for each column.

Then you could add six bytes (double byte encoding) for every column * no. of records to account for the enclosing quotation marks and separators between columns.

Comment: Thanks Lars, it didn't work, unfortunatly. When I do a Sum of umcompressed data for a table it gives for example 386332 and my csv file size is 344KB so I need maybe to reduce something to get the result.

Comment: Well, the uncompressed size is always only an estimation. Also, it's in Bytes, so to me this converts to 377KB which is not too bad for an estimation.